# sort value from function in cgridview

Tags: php, sorting, yii, cgridview

i have a table that one of column has value from function

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'camera-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'name'=>'location', 
        'header'=>'Location', 
        'value'=>'$data->location->name'
    ),
    array(
        'header'=>'Last Date',
        'value'=>'$data->myfunction($data->location->name)'
    ),
),)); ?>
```

my questions is:

1. how to sort column Last Date?
2. there's chance the Last Date is null. So, if i want to display rows with Last Date is not null, what i'm suppose to do?

Thanks before :)

Comment: you mean default sort?

Comment: @hoangvu68 i mean, i can sort by Last Date (return from function) in table as i can sort another column based on model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end, i found this solution. 
overall, i must make my custom variable as SQL query. So, i can sort or search custom variable like other variable from database.

in mymodel,

1. declare new variable
   `public $LAST_DATE;`
2. add $criteria

`$criteria->select = array('*','COALESCE(location.name, \'\') AS LAST_DATE');
$criteria->order = 'LAST_DATE DESC';
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'LAST_DATE DESC',
            'attributes' => array(
                'LAST_DATE'=>array(
                    'asc'=>'COALESCE(location.name, \'\')',
                    'desc'=>'COALESCE(location.name, \'\') DESC',
                ),
                '*',
            ),
        ),`

Answer (score 1):

Sorting will look like this:

```
    $sort = new CSort;
    $criteria->with = array(
        'location'
    );

    /* Sort criteria */
    $sort->attributes = array(
        'col_name'=>array(
            'asc'=>"location.date asc",
            'desc'=>"location.date desc",
        ),
        '*',
    );

    /* Default Sort Order*/
    $sort->defaultOrder= array(
        'col_name'=>CSort::SORT_ASC,
    );

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>20),
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>$sort,
    ));
```

And NULL you need to check in the row value:

```
  'value'=>'$data->location ? $data->myfunction($data->location->name) : ""'
```

If you don't have any column in database that you can order by, you should select all record from database, then sort them manually and put into CArrayDataProvider.

Comment: what if i don't have `location.date`? and Last Date is from myfunction()

Comment: that means you can't order rows in mysql?

Comment: for example, myfunction(location) return '21 Apr 2014', this value as Last Date column. And i want in table, i can sort by Last Date, which not from database.

Comment: you should select all record from database, then sort them manually and put into CArrayDataProvider

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex said the only solution, without editing the database, is to read ALL the records from the database, apply your function to each model and then sort them manually. Not only will this be a memory hog for a large table, it is also terribly inefficient since a) you will discard most of the records from the database if you are using pagination and b) your custom sorting method will most likely be slower than your database's.

From the information you've given, my solution would be to add an additional field to your table and set it to the result of `$data->myfunction($data->location->name)'`. A `CActiveDataProvider` with `defaultOrder` set can the be used to feed the `CGridView`.